# Batch - for /f loops running SET commands

Tags: batch-file

This is my code:

```
:LevelSave
cls & echo.Choose a save file: & echo.
if exist savedata.txt (
for /f "tokens=*" %%P in ('type savedata.txt') do (
%%P
set /a q=q+1
echo. [!q!] !savename! - !lastcd!
set r=!r!!q!
)
)
```

This is the contents of savedata.txt

```
set savename=save1 && set lastcd=start\Continue on path
```

But when run, it outputs this:

```
Choose a save file:

save1 && set lastcd=start\Continue on path - save1
```

even when I remove the `echo`.

I've tried using different arrangements of quotes in the savedata.txt, though I think the problem is actually somewhere in the for command. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you check if you run the correct file and if savedata.txt is stored in the directory where you run it from? Add some echo statements to see what part of the script is executed and which not.

Answer (score 1):

Just put a `call` before the 2 `set` in your `savedata.txt`

savedata.txt :

```
call set savename=save1 && call set lastcd=start\Continue on path
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround:

savedata.txt

```
save1|start\Continue on path
save2|end\fallen into the pit
```

code

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:LevelSave
cls & echo.Choose a save file: & echo.
if exist savedata.txt (
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=|" %%P in ('type savedata.txt') do (
set savename=%%P
set lastcd=%%Q
set /a q=q+1
echo. [!q!] !savename! - !lastcd!
set r=!r!!q!
)
)
pause
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with more variables in the savedata.txt? E.g. savename|save1 lastcd|blah... var3|blah var4|blah... etc for an infinite amount of variables?

Comment: infinite - no.  You can have more items however.  A usual way to arrange save game data is to write the information in a series of individual lines and then read them into an array, or series of variables, to restore them.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
:LevelSave
cls & echo.Choose a save file: & echo.
SET savename=some name&SET lastcd=somelastcd&SET q=6
::@ECHO on
if exist q20731333.txt (
for /f "tokens=*" %%P in ('type q20731333.txt') do (
CALL :sub "%%P"
set /a q=q+1
echo. [!q!] !savename! - !lastcd!
set r=!r!!q!
)
)
GOTO :EOF

:sub
%~1
GOTO :eof
```

This should work... I've changed the filename for my testing...and instantiated variablenames.